# How to change back button from text to image in UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  
                               initWithImage:@"rGoBack" 
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain  
                               target:nil action:nil];  
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;  
[backButton release];
```

I use this source. but It doesn't work. I don't know why not. please..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the first glance:

```
initWithImage:@"rGoBack"
```

here `UIImage` parameter required and `NSString` is passed instead. Try writing something like:

```
initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rGoBack.png"]; // or whatever image name you have
```